# Apache Kafka + MongoDB weird behaviour when time measure

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-kafka, slowdown

I have a problem when measuring the write time from Kafka to MongoDB.
These are my docker-compose files:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 35000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_1://broker:29092,LISTENER_2://broker:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_1://broker:29092,LISTENER_2://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_1:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_2:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: "anonymous"
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 35000
      
  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:latest
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081    
          
  connect:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: connect.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "35000:35000"
      - "8083:8083"
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    networks:
      - localnet
    environment:
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 35000
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: connect-cluster-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS: 180000
      CONNECT_METADATA_MAX_AGE_MS: 180000
      CONNECT_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"

  mongo1:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo1
    command: --replSet rs0 --oplogSize 128
    ports:
      - "35001:27017"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - connect
    networks:
      - localnet
    restart: always

  mongo1-setup:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo1-setup
    volumes: 
      - ./config-replica.js:/config-replica.js
    depends_on:
      - mongo1
    networks:
      - localnet
    entrypoint:
      [
        "bash",
        "-c",
        "sleep 10 && mongosh --host mongo1:27017 config-replica.js && sleep 10",
      ]
    restart: "no"
    
    
  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:latest
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021 
    networks:
      - localnet

networks:
  localnet:
    attachable: true
```

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt --verbose mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:latest


ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
```

a Connector configuration:

```
{
    "name": "mongo-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
        "topics": "IoT",
        "connection.uri": "mongodb://mongo1",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "database": "IoT",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "writemodel.strategy": "org.example.klas",
        "collection": "devices",
        "transforms": "InsertField",
        "transforms.InsertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field": "insertedToKafka",
        "timeseries.timefield": "measureTime",
        "timeseries.timefield.auto.convert": "true",
        "timeseries.timefield.auto.convert.date.format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
    }
}
```

And my custom write strategy:

```
package org.example;

import com.mongodb.client.model.InsertOneModel;
import com.mongodb.client.model.WriteModel;
import com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.SinkDocument;
import com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.UpdateOneTimestampsStrategy;
import com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.WriteModelStrategy;
import org.bson.BsonDateTime;
import org.bson.BsonDocument;

public class klas implements WriteModelStrategy {

    private final static String ID_FIELD_NAME = "_id";
    private final static String EVENT_TYPE_FIELD_NAME = "eventType";
    @Override
    public WriteModel<BsonDocument> createWriteModel(SinkDocument sinkDocument) {
        BsonDocument vd = (BsonDocument)sinkDocument.getValueDoc().orElseThrow(() -> {
            return new RuntimeException("Could not build the WriteModel,the value document was missing unexpectedly");
        });
        vd = vd.append("insertTime",new BsonDateTime(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        return new InsertOneModel(vd);
    }
}
```

Generally I would like to measure how much time do I need to consume data from Apache Kafka and save data in MongoDB.
To get time I put data into kafka I have used this part of configuration file

```
"transforms": "InsertField",
"transforms.InsertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
"transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field": "insertedToKafka"
```

Document in MongoDB looks like:

```
{
    measureTime: ISODate("2023-07-15T19:39:15.977Z"),
    _id: ObjectId("64b3df9edcf32746323e15fe"),
    value: 91.40457465058628,
    insertedToKafka: Long("1689509790584"),
    externalId: Long("4355"),
    deviceId: '0d036333-83aa-4565-80ad-d4db4238a910',
    deviceName: 'TERMOMETER',
    insertTime: ISODate("2023-07-16T12:16:30.587Z")
  }
```

To save time when MongoDB save data I have used upper write model strategy(insertTime in document)

I used Java program to send data on Kafka. It work quite well but in case I want to slow down (using Thread.sleep(20)) a while loop which put data into Kafka sometimes insertTime > insertedToKafka.
Is this problem with Kafka or with Thread.sleep()?  How could I avoid it?

This is code I have been using to send data on Kafka

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    List<String> anotherList = new ArrayList<>();



    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
    String topic = "IoT";
    String line;
    String kafkaIndex="0";
        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("TERMOMETER"))
            {
                kafkaIndex = "1";
            }
            if(line.contains("HIGROMETER"))
            {
                kafkaIndex = "3";
            }
            if(line.contains("BAROMETER"))
            {
                kafkaIndex = "4";
            }

            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic,kafkaIndex, line);
            var x = producer.send(record, (recordMetadata, e) -> {
                if (e == null) {
                    // the record was successfully sent
                    anotherList.add(String.valueOf(recordMetadata.timestamp()));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error while producing"+e);
                }
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            producer.flush();

        }
    producer.close();
        givenDataArray_whenConvertToCSV_thenOutputCreated(anotherList,"timeFromKafka.csv");

    }
```

When I add `Thread.sleep(20)` a   subtraction between insertTime and insertedToKafa sometimes is between -50k ms and +50k ms

I have been looking for any solution or tip but can't find anything usefull

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Yes, you can delay flushing a producer, but you can try `linger.ms` rather than sleeping the thread

Comment: Hi.
In general, I would like to test different times when kafka will receive data. I want kafka to consume data as soon as possible, but receive it at different time intervals. Could I achive this using linger.ms ?

Comment: In general, Kafka consumers will always read as soon as the data is available. If you want to prevent the producer from sending data to the broker, then yes, you can block the thread, or have it linger and wait for data to be added to the buffer before any network request is done

Comment: @OneCricketeer Prevent producer from sending data is exacly what I want to achive. I can't use `linger.ms` because I would like to slow down the generation of data.  I have added  code I use to send maybe there is a problem there?

Comment: Hard to say, but the producer can flush its buffer (based on `batch.size`) before `Thread.sleep` finishes, and before you manually flush. Also, the insertField transform will run within the JVM context of the Connect worker, and is completely unrelated to the Producer which can add its own timestamp to the record manually from the `ProducerRecord` constructor

Comment: So I will try to increase `batch.size` Thank's for your help,.If you have any other ideas, I'd love to read them

Comment: One question, You have said Producer can add its own timestamp. How can I achive it? When I use `recordMetadata.timestamp()` I get exacly same time as from insertField transform

Comment: The constructor for ProducerRecord accepts a timestamp, in addition to topic, key, and value. However, that just overrides the default "current time". It won't delay anything